# Javascript slider not working in some of the countries

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a javascript slider(swiper) for one of my swiss client,The slider is working for Indian network providers but its not working in swiss network providers.I changed the IP to swiss in INDIA,its working fine,but in switzerland its not working.Any suggestions??Are there any blocks for javascript in a region??

Comment: Please provide more details on this, as in your code, link to the site etc.,

Comment: Why don't you switch to some other CDN or just include the library locally?

Comment: I've seen that China blocks the Google CDN. I wouldn't expect Switzerland to do it.